# How to access parameter that passed on a anchor tag to get link button click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

Here is the code I used to display all tags on client side... and I want to get parameter passed on anchor tag function into serverside linkbutton click

```
<ul class="list_load">
    <% for (int i = 0; i < dtscrippsyearcount.Rows.Count; i++)
        { %>
    <li class="list_item">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkdisplaytag" OnClick="lnkdisplaytag_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        <a href="#" id="<%=dtscrippsyearcount.Rows[i]["TagId"].ToString() %>" onclick="javascript:GetSelectedTag('<%=dtscrippsyearcount.Rows[i]["TagId"].ToString() %>')"><%=dtscrippsyearcount.Rows[i]["TagName"].ToString() %></a></li>
    <%} %>
</ul>            


function GetSelectedTag(Tagid) {
    __doPostBack('lnkdisplaytag ', Tagid)
    $("#lnkdisplaytag").click();
     return true;
}
```

Code behind

```
protected void lnkdisplaytag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];////want to get tagid here
}
```

Comment: add a new attribute from server side in LinkButton or anchor tag
then get value of it by passing this in function and then retrive from attribute eg : <a tag="111" id="112" onclick="MyFunction(this)">

MyFunction(selector){
var tag=$(this.id).attr("tag");
}

Something time that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start using actual Contols, like a Repeater instead of creating an inline loop.
In the snippet below a simple working example of how to use a Repeater, fill it with data and getting the TagID when a LinkButton is clicked.

First, add a Repeater to the aspx page with a LinkButton in the ItemTemplate. Note the use of `OnCommand` instead of `OnClick` and the `CommandArgument` property.

```
<ul class="list_load">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <li class="list_item">

                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkdisplaytag" 
                   OnCommand="lnkdisplaytag_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TagId") %>'
                   Text='<%# Eval("TagName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

            </li>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

To fill a Repeater you need to do the following in code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = dtscrippsyearcount;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Then, when a LinkButton is clicked, you can get the `CommandArgument` value easily.

```
protected void lnkdisplaytag_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```